# Java: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a client for vk.com and got an error.

Im using fragments and i think it caused by fragments.

Process: ru.dennes544.vkapp, PID: 9357
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.perm.kate.api.Api.getProfiles(java.util.Collection, java.util.Collection, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at ru.dennes544.vkapp.Profile$1.run(Profile.java:89)

few lines of code:

```
private void loadAccInfo(){
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Collection uid = new ArrayList();
            try {
                uid.add(account.user_id);
                profiles = api.getProfiles(uid, null, "sex", "Nom", null, null).get(0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (KException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and declaration of getProfiles:

```
public ArrayList<User> getProfiles(Collection<Long> uids, Collection<String> domains, String fields, String name_case, String captcha_key, String captcha_sid) throws IOException, JSONException, KException{
    if (uids == null && domains == null)
        return null;
    if ((uids != null && uids.size() == 0) || (domains != null && domains.size() == 0))
        return null;
    Params params = new Params("users.get");
    if (uids != null && uids.size() > 0)
        params.put("user_ids",arrayToString(uids));
    if (domains != null && domains.size() > 0)
        params.put("user_ids",arrayToString(domains));
    params.put("fields",fields);
    params.put("name_case",name_case);
    addCaptchaParams(captcha_key, captcha_sid, params);
    JSONObject root = sendRequest(params);
    JSONArray array=root.optJSONArray("response");
    return User.parseUsers(array);
}
```

Comment: *getProfiles()* can return NULL, so maybe the *api.getProfiles().get(0);* cause the NullPointerException ( you are trying to get a value from null object)

Comment: @Rami, thing is, without fragments, just in activity, that code working

Comment: @Rami, if u know and can help me, please help!

Comment: api is null. how do you initialize it ?

Comment: @ben75, just like in activity. Api api;

Comment: So `api` is not initialized. There MUST be something different in your Activity code (probably in the onCreate) to initialize `api`.

Comment: @ben75, dammit, u are right! there is an initialization